# Action method of a Controller in Laravel 5.5

Tags: forms, controller, action, laravel-5.5

I have a Form like

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Users\BlogController@storeGallery')) }}
```

I am getting error like

```
(2/2) ErrorException
Action App\Http\Controllers\Users\BlogController@storeGallery not defined. (View: /var/www/html/my-dev/resources/views/users/blog/archive.blade.php)
```

But I am not getting any error if I use `{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'Users\BlogController@publish')) }}`

This `publish` method is created by another developer before and I tried to develop `storeGallery` method.

Why I am getting error could anyone say ?

Comment: do you actually have any route that goes to `Users\BlogController@storeGallery` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set 'uses' like that. This not the way. You need to define `namespace` for your route!

Your route should be;

```
Route::namespace('Users')->group(function () {
    Route::get('url','Controller@function')
});
```

And in your form;

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'BlogController@storeGallery']) !!}
```

Try like that. It should works

Also you can read the documentation about namepaces groups in [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-namespaces)

Comment: You do not have to define the namespace like that, the way they did it is perfectly fine ... you can define it either way  ... also your action in the form is now incorrect

Comment: it just typo, As I know, when we we create sub category for controller, we should define namespace for our route ? Also this is what documentation says

Answer (score 0):

The Exception 2/2: `Action App\Http\Controllers\Users\BlogController@storeGallery not defined` makes me want to believe there is no route defined that goes to that method on that controller.

`@publish` probably has a route defined that points to it. You can check with `php artisan route:list`.

Check the needed routes file and see if there is a route defined. If the route is defined try running `php artisan route:clear` to clear the route cache, or `php artisan route:cache` to re-cache the routes. If the route isn't defined any where, define it. (You may need to run one of those artisan commands above after defining the route)

It might be wise to see if Exception 1/2 has anything interesting going on or not as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['BlogController@storeGallery', $Users->id], 'method' =>'POST']) !!}
```

I hope this will help you!